# Can you heal at the moment you get KO'd?

Tags: fortune-and-glory

During my last game of Fortune and Glory, I played the event card Blizzard on another player (do d6 Wounds if the player/villain is in an Ice space). I rolled 6 damage, and he was playing Shelly Hargrove, who can take a maximum of 4 Wounds. He prevented 2 Wounds between his Defense and another item, but then he used the [Spunky](http://www.flyingfrogwiki.com/ffpwiki/index.php?title=Ability:Spunky) ability to "heal" two Wounds, thus avoiding being KO'd. Here's what the Spunky ability says:

> May pay 2 Glory at any time to Heal a Wound (except during a Fight Round).

Can you use abilities that heal you to prevent Wounds that would KO you, or does being KO'd prevent healing?

Answer (score 1):

For reference: [the rulebook.](http://www.flyingfrog.net/fortuneandglory/pdf%5CFANG_Rulebook_FINAL_WEB.pdf)

There are 2 key phrases:

> May pay 2 Glory ***at any time*** to Heal a Wound (***except during a Fight Round***).

So lets assess 2 possibilities - **Fighting** and **Everything Else**.

**Fighting**:

If you are KO'd in a fight then it is clearly a no as this ability doesn't work during a fight round.

**NOTE:**

> Sometimes a card will say that it
>   cannot be used ‘during a Fight Round’. Cards like this may
>   however, still be used *between* Fight Rounds.

If you survive with at least one wound you can use this in between Fight Rounds as the round ends before another begins.

**Everything Else:**

Since the ability may be used at ***any time*** then you can use it while taking damage to prevent KO*. In your example an event occurred, not a fight so this ability can be used.

*Nothing it the rulebook explicitly says a KO prevents this ability so I would interpret it this way.

Comment: Since it heals damage, wouldn't you get KO'd first before you heal? (And the game clearly defines what happens when you get KO'd.)

Comment: My interpretation is based on experience with many other games where this is how it would work. 'Any time' normally means just that even when it seems odd like in this instance. If they had intended differently there would normally be an exception in the FAQ and there is not in this case.

Comment: Does seem strange to be able to use the heal for this. As the event does 6 hits the question to me is if the hits are all done at the same time or one at a time allowing for someone to use an ability in between.

Comment: Lots of games have some kind of instant heal ability. It comes at the loss of 2 Glory which can hamper your character later. In the example you would need 4 Glory to prevent the damage which seems fair.